# Hyphen and Underscore should never be continuous but can be present in the string more than once

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, regex-negation

I have a requirement, where i have to validate a field in Excel.

### Validations:

1. Field should start and end with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` but not with any special chars `[-_]`
2. It cannot contain "-" and "_" continuously more than once.

   **Example:**

   `A--Badasd` (Not allowed)
   `A__Bsdasdas` (Not allowed)
   `A-_fdsfdsd` (Not Allowed)
   `A_-sfsdfsdf` (Not allowed)
   `A-B-adf` (allowed)
   `A_b_adads` (allowed)

I came up with this following regex, however, it doesn't seem to accept even the non-continuous entries of "-" and "_".

```
^[a-zA-z0-9]+(([\xFF01-\xFF5E]+|[\\-\\_])+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

`[\xFF01-\xFF5E]` is to not allow any double width characters, so please ignore it as it is working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: [`^(?!.*[-_]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9][\xFF01-\xFF5E_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/9xdA3J/1). Or to allow 1 char strings, [`^(?!.*[-_]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[\xFF01-\xFF5E_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/9xdA3J/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a neat one. Worked like a charm!

Comment: See my answer below. Please consider accepting if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only suggest a lookahead based pattern (as `[\xFF01-\xFF5E]` matches `_` and restricting it in JS regex will make the pattern more cumbersome):

```
/^[a-z0-9](?:(?!.*?[-_]{2})[\xFF01-\xFF5E-]*[a-z0-9])?$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xdA3J/4).

This pattern will match strings of 1 char length, too, and will only match those strings starting and ending with an ASCII alphanumeric char and not having `--`, `_-`, `-_` and `__` in them.

If you want to "block" strings of length 1, i.e. set the minimum match length to 2, you should remove `(?:` and `)?` from the pattern above:

```
/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[-_]{2})[\xFF01-\xFF5E-]*[a-z0-9]$/i
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z0-9]` - an alphanumeric ASCII char
- `(?:(?!.*?[-_]{2})[\xFF01-\xFF5E_-]*[a-z0-9])?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences) sequence of:

  - `(?!.*?[-_]{2})` - a lookahead check that will fail the match if there are 2 consecutive `-` or `_` anywhere after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `[\xFF01-\xFF5E-]*` - any char in the `\xFF01-\xFF5E` range or/and `-`
  - `[a-z0-9]` - an alphanumeric ASCII char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This works like a charm, however, I went with the 1st suggestion you made, which even blocks single char strings. Just to be more stringent on the data validation part...

Comment: Yes, these requirements should be posted in the question itself. But you may just remove `(?:` and the last `)?` and it will also "block" 1-char strings. I added the pattern variation for strings of length 2 and up to the answer.